# How to take two out of order CSV's and match by ID columns from each CSV and Inject the mac address to the matched ID from another CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

How to take two out of order  CSV's and match by ID columns from each CSV and Inject the mac address to the matched ID from another CSV?

Answer (score 0):

> Takes two CSV's groups two columns from first dict `Unique Card ID`
> and `mac`
>
> then compares it to see if there is a match from second dict for
> `Bluetooth code`
>
> If a match is found, it will inject the first dict `mac` into the
> empty column
>
> `client_mac` next to the `Bluetooth code` code that it matches on from
> the first dictionary

```
import pandas as pd

df_firstDict = pd.read_csv("seeds/Card Test Data - Sheet1.csv")
dict_compare = {row["Unique Card ID"]: row["MAC"] 
for index, row in df_firstDict[['Unique Card ID', 'MAC']].iterrows()}


df_secondDict = pd.read_csv("seeds/SalasTestData - Sheet1.csv")
df_compare = df_secondDict["Bluetooth code"].map(lambda x: dict_compare.get(x))
df_secondDict.drop(columns=["client_mac"], inplace=True)
df_secondDict["client_mac"] = df_compare

print(dict_compare)
```